# best way to remove all objects in a table

Tags: arrays, lua, coronasdk, lua-table

```
for i = 1, #allblocks do      to remove all objects in the table
Removing_block = table.remove(allblocks, 1)
Removing_block:removeSelf() 
Removing_block=nil
end
```

this is the best way I found that is working.
somone has a better way?

Comment: Running that loop backwards will be better as it doesn't require re-indexing the table each time through the loop.

Comment: thanks but I cant do that. object are constantly added

Comment: I don't understand. You have code **adding** elements to this table at the same time as this loop to remove them is running? How? Adding once the loop is finished doesn't matter.

Comment: There appears to be an unstated assumption in the question and the answers that "all object in a table' means the sequence in a table. [We use the term sequence to denote a table where the set of all positive numeric keys is equal to {1..n} for some non-negative integer n, which is called the length of the sequence.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1)

Comment: [Corona Forums: Clear Table](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/14534-clear-table/)

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest way:

```
for i = 1, #allblocks do
  allblocks[i]:removeSelf() 
  allblocks[i] = nil
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Etan's comment:

Change your code to:

```
for i = #allblocks, 1, -1 do
  Removing_block = table.remove(allblocks, i)
  Removing_block:removeSelf()
  Removing_block = nil
end
```

I'm guessing for some reason or another you can't do

```
allblocks = {}
```

to reset it? You're essentially doing the same thing, it appears.

Comment: This calculates the size of the table each time. There's no need for that. Invert the bits in the `for` loop: `for i = #allblocks, 1 do` and just use `i` in the `table.remove` call. And `allblocks = {}` doesn't call `removeSelf` on each object which is possibly/probably an important detail.

Comment: Quite true. And thanks for pointing that out, with the invert. I originally had that thought, got sidetracked, wrote something else, and neglected to remember my original thought. Kudos to you, since it was your idea in the first place. :)

Comment: Don't forget the -1 when going down :)

Comment: BTW, the default position for table.remove() is the last element, so going up or down really makes no difference if you simply use table.remove(allblocks) without giving any position.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions: Table is a list indexed 1..n

Given that table.remove() also returns the just removed item, the simplest (shortest) way is possibly this:

```
for i = 1, #allblocks do
  table.remove(allblocks):removeSelf()
end
```